# React onChange event not updated correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit**: Never mind, it was a typo. I passed the `brokersListFilter` from the state instead of using the event value .

I'm trying to create a filter component which allows users to filter the data from a web service Get request . My code :

```
    <TextField
      id="filter"
      helperText={labels.filterHelperText}
      value={this.props.brokersListFilter}
      onChange={this.onFilterChange}
      className={this.props.classes.textField}
      }}
    />
```

And `onFilterChange` :

```
 onFilterChange = (event) => {
   this.props.setBrokersListFilter(event)
   this.props.getBrokers(this.props.brokersListPage, this.props.brokersListFilter)
 }
```

The code works , but with a "delay" , if I type "222" for example the data is being filtered as by "22" , same goes for deleting , when I discard a number from "222" to "22" then the data is being filtered by "222" . It's like it is using the last state and not the current one . Why is this happening ?

Comment: Can you post your full code please? This is likely a `setState` issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening due to the fact that `setState` is [actually async](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3).

Comment: I've updated the question. I use dispatch and not setState, but yes one of my calls is async ..

Comment: Never mind. It was a typo , I passed the state value instead of the event value. You can delete the answer so I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of updating the global store variable `brokersListFilter` and calling the function `getBrokers` next line itself with the props value `brokersListFilter` will not get updated in the store. You can try with `componentDidUpdate` as below and remove the line `this.props.getBrokers` from `onFilterChange` function.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(this.props.brokersListFilter !== prevProps.brokersListFilter){
   this.props.getBrokers(this.props.brokersListPage, this.props.brokersListFilter)
 }
}
```